# How to set cutom template for kendo grid columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to set Kendo grid action button Icon based on value. My code as follows,

```
function InitProductServicesGrid() {
    var prodServiceDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            type: "json",
            read:
                {
                    url: SERVER_PATH + "/LTSService/ProductsService.asmx/GetProductServiceDetailsList",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: GetAdditonalData,
                    datatype: "json"
                },
            update:
            {
                url: SERVER_PATH + "/LTSService/ProductsService.asmx/SaveProductService",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                datatype: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (result) {
                return JSON.parse(result.d);
            },
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "int" },
                    ServiceTime: { type: "string" },
                    IsActive: { type: "boolean"}
                }
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function (e) {
            if (e.type === "destroy") {
                var grid = $("#productServicesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.xhr !== undefined && e.xhr !== null) {
                var messageBody = e.xhr.responseJSON.Message;
                ShowGritterMessage("Errors", messageBody, false, '../App_Themes/Default/LtsImages/errorMessageIcon_large.png');
                var grid = $("#productServicesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.cancelChanges();
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
    });

    $("#productServicesGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: prodServiceDataSource,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: false,
        pageable: true,
        dataBound: gridDataBound,
        editable: {
            mode: "inline",
            confirmation: false
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", title: "", hidden: true },
            {
                field: "ServiceTime",
                title: "Time Standard",
                sortable: false,
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var serviceTimeTxtBox = RenderServiceTime();
                    $(serviceTimeTxtBox).appendTo(container);
                },
                headerTemplate: '<a class="k-link" href="#" title="Time Standard">Time Standard</a>'
            },
            {
                title: "Action", command: [
                    {
                        name: "hideRow",
                        click: hideRow,
                        template: comandTemplate
                    }
                ],
                width: "150px"
            }
        ]
    });

}
```

I wrote a custom template function as follows,

```
function comandTemplate(model) {

    if (model.IsActive == true) {
        return '<a title="Hide" class="k-grid-hideRow k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-lock"></span></a><a title="Hide"></a>';
    }
    else {
        return '<a title="Show" class="k-grid-hideRow k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-unlock"></span></a><a title="Show"></a>';
    }
}
```

But when I debug the I saw the following value for model value.

[image]

I followed [this sample code](http://dojo.telerik.com/AdAKO) as well. here you can see, I also set the custom template like the sample code. Please help me to solve this. Why I can't access model `IsActive` value from `comandTemplate` function.

**Updated**

When clicking `hideRow` action, I access the dataItem as follows.

```
function hideRow(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        if (dataItem.IsActive == true) {
            dataItem.IsActive = false;
        }
        else {
            dataItem.IsActive = true;
        }
}
```

Is there any possible way to access data from template function as above or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach because you can't access grid data while rendering and populating grid.

My suggestion is to use two actions and hide it based on the flag (in your case `IsActive`).

Something like this: [Custom command](https://dojo.telerik.com/arEfINij)

**NOTE**: in `visible` function you can access item!

**EDIT**: you can access it and change it on `dataBound` traversing through all data. 
Check this example: [Data bound](http://dojo.telerik.com/iHuVaKeb)

Comment: please look at my updated question. when I clicking the `hideRow` I can access the data. Is there any possible way to do the same thing for access value from the template?

Comment: You can access it on click and on visible events. You need to access it while populating and rendering grid and I think that's not possible.

Comment: You can do it on data bound event of grid, I updated answer

Comment: please look my code. https://pastebin.com/idEcS9CZ . in there `const isActive = dataItem.isActive;` value showing as undefined, May I know why? please help me

Comment: As I said before....you **can't** access `dataItem` inside  template  of `command`

Comment: This is how I would do it in your case: https://dojo.telerik.com/OvobaKEg

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the advantage of relying on the grid commands. You can render any button you want yourself and and use the dataBound event to bind a click handler:

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      {
        template: function(dataItem) {
            const isActive = dataItem.isActive;
            return `<a title=${isActive ? "Hide": "Show"} class="k-grid-hideRow k-button"><span class="k-icon k-i-${isActive ? 'lock' : 'unlock'}"></span></a>`
        }      
      }
    ],
    dataBound: function(e) {
      e.sender.tbody.find(".k-grid-hideRow").click(evt => {
        const row = evt.target.closest("tr")
        const dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row)
        dataItem.set("isActive", !dataItem.isActive)
      })            
    },
    dataSource: [{ name: "Jane Doe", isActive: false }, { name: "Jane Doe", isActive: true }]
  });
```

Runnable Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/eTiyeCiJ

Comment: Why this not working in IE browser. I think because of array fucntion `click(evt =>`.  is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Please look my complete code:   https://pastebin.com/idEcS9CZ . in there `const isActive = dataItem.isActive;` value showing as undefined, May I know why? please help me

Comment: @Adam `console.log` your dataItem, check what's there and remember the properties are case-sensitive. I based my dojo on the one by @dev_in_progress where it starts with a lower case.

Comment: its shows as `Undefined` please look this image https://i.imgur.com/0I2ZAkB.png I think I can Access `dataitem` from action commands :( please look my complete code as well

Comment: I tried your code as follows, https://pastebin.com/2cAxj8Mb . I added action inside action command, Its also return `Undefined`. That is the main issue. please look pastebin code(I bit changed your code)

Comment: @Adam just because you named it dataItem does not mean it's the dataItem. It is in fact a special options object for the special command template, with things like `text` or `iconClass`, but, as you can see, not your `isActive` .

Comment: So what is your suggesion,Sorry I'm not clear your comment

Comment: You. Cannot. Access. The. DataItem. In. The. Command. Template. Check the source of the Kendo Grid (the grid is in the professional version, so you must have a valid license) and check the method _createButton: no dataItem there. You have been given two working solutions, my suggestion is to use either one of them.